# Wait for all files to update, then download them

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, jszip

I'm using the library JSZip to create .png files and add them to a zip archive to be downloaded. The problem comes when I add too many large files.

I use a set of for loops to add the files to the zip then activate an automatic download. The issue seems to be that the download starts before the files have been updated so they end up with no data.

```
for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) { // Loop for rows
  for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) { // Loop for cols
    if (cropSrc[row][col]) { // If data for cropped img exists
      var fileName = row + "" + col + ".png";
      zip.file(fileName, cropSrc[row][col].src, {
        base64: true
      }); // Add file to zip

      zip.file(fileName).async("uint8array").then(function(u8) { // Once file is complete... I think
        console.log("done");
      });

    }
  }
}

// Download zip file
zip.generateAsync({
  type: "base64"
}).then(function(base64) {
  window.location = "data:application/zip;base64," + base64;
});
```

I have to make sure I wait till all files have been updated before downloading, how would I do this using async functions?

Here is [JSZip Async Documentation](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_zipobject/async.html)

---

Not sure if this will help but here is a more complete look at the full code, I'm using SAPUI5 and developing in SAP Web IDE:

```
var cropSrc = {
    0: {
        0:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        1:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        2:{src:"base64 data placeholder"}
    },
    1: {
        0:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        1:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        2:{src:"base64 data placeholder"}
    },
    2: {
        0:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        1:{src:"base64 data placeholder"},
        2:{src:"base64 data placeholder"}
    }
};

sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "SAP_SARAH_ML_Project/libs/jszip", // Enables the jszip library (imports)
], function(Controller, jszipjs) { // Second part of importing
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("SAP_SARAH_ML_Project.controller.View1", {

        zipImg: function() {
            for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) { // Loop for rows
                for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) { // Loop for cols
                    if (cropSrc[row][col]) { // If data for cropped img exists
                        var fileName = row + "" + col + ".png";
                        zip.file(fileName, cropSrc[row][col].src, {
                            base64: true
                        }); // Add file to zip

                        zip.file(fileName).async("uint8array").then(function(u8) { // Once file is complete... I think
                            console.log("done");
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            // Download zip file
            zip.generateAsync({
                type: "base64"
            }).then(function(base64) {
                window.location = "data:application/zip;base64," + base64;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Promise.all for this:

```
let arr = [addFilePromise('file1'),addFilePromise('file2'),addFilePromise('file3')]
Promise.all(arr).then(zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"}))
```

EDIT:

```
let fileAddActions = [];

let addFilePromise = function(filename){
    zip.file(fileName, cropSrc[row][col].src, {
        base64: true
    }); 

    return zip.file(fileName).async("uint8array")
}


for (var row = 0; row < 3; row++) { // Loop for rows
    for (var col = 0; col < 3; col++) { // Loop for cols
        if (cropSrc[row][col]) { // If data for cropped img exists
        var fileName = row + "" + col + ".png";
        fileAddActions.push(addFilePromise(fileName))

        }
    }
}


Promise.all(fileAddActions).then(zip.generateAsync({type:"base64"})).then(base64 => {
    indow.location = "data:application/zip;base64," + base64;
})
```

something like this should work, also i recommend this article:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I'm new to async, what is the addFilePromise piece? Could you maybe format this in how I would have it for my function? I really appreciate it

Comment: Thank you @mr.void I tried a few times but I can't tell if it's really waiting for the promises to complete. I tried debugging in chrome but once the promise.all is called I can't access the array to check if the promises are really complete or if the zip is correct. (You missed a 'w' in window btw.) I really appreciate the help. When I run it it still makes the browser go to "about:blank" and doesn't download anything. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: which lib are you using? i will try to make a more complete example

Comment: I am using the [JSZip library](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) I am also developing in SAPUI5 using the SAP Web IDE

Comment: I updated the question to include a more holistic look at my code too. Thanks for the help!

Comment: works like expected: https://jsfiddle.net/xywar3e8/1/ , maybe you reach the limitations of the lib with your filesize (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/limitations.html)

Comment: I fooled around with it more and now I'm getting "jszip invalid base64 input, bad content length." so thank you for all your help :) On to the next error! haha

Answer (score 0):

Since async returns a Promise, you can make the function where you are doing the for loop an async/await function

```
async functionName() {
   for loop...
      let res = await zip.file(fileName).async("uint8array");
}
```

Comment: I added the fuller version of my code to the question. SAPUI5 seems to have functions as part of objects so I don't know how I would do this within that. Maybe you could shed some light on that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59066014/downloading-large-number-of-files-in-frontend-using-jszip/60600262#60600262)

It uses something called parallelimit which acts as a semaphore to process the files asynchronously in a limited amount and then zips it.