# Problem regarding an asynchronous function and how I should correctly run it synchronously

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following algorithm:

```js
// Main Function
    // Get some local data
    // Convert to some format I need to edit
    // Loop through user's local images
        // Edit the converted data to add the image's names to it
        // Convert IMAGE to base64 and add result into zip file
        that.uriToBase64(imageFilePath).then((result) => {
            console.log("image as base64: ", result);
            zip.file(arrayItem2.name, result, {base64: true});
        });

    // Convert data again to save it
    // Add data to zip file
    // Generate zip file and save it in user's local storage

//uriToBase64() function
```

---

**My problem**

The step ‘Add data to zip file’ happens before the images are added to zip file. Although the ‘Convert IMAGE to base64’ step has a .then, everything inside happens only after everything is finished. In this case, my zip file is being saved without the images. I tried to make this step work synchronously, using async/await syntax in countless ways, but I couldn’t make it work the way I expected, which is adding the image data inside the zip file within each iteration.

Since the result of uriToBase64() function is a Promise, using .then to get the result data should “pause” the loop until the data is added by the zip.file() command, then iterate with the next image, right? If not, what is the correct way to wait for it, taking into account the current structure of the algorithm?

---

**Attempts**

*Attempt 1*

I tried some nasty things to make this work, unsuccessful again.
My new algorithm:

```js
// Main Function
    // Get some local data
    // Convert to some format I need and add to a global variable
    // Loop through user's local images
        // Add +1 to new global variable 'imageCounter'
        // Edit the converted data (now in global variable) to add the image's names to it
        // Convert IMAGE to base64 and add result into zip file
        that.uriToBase64(imageFilePath).then((result) => {
            console.log("image as base64: ", result);
            zip.file(arrayItem2.name, result, {base64: true});
            that.prepareForWrite();

            // Check if this is the last iteration and run function again.
            if (thisIsLastIteration == true) { that.prepareForWrite(); }                        
        });

//prepareForWrite() function
    // imageCounter - 1
    // if imageCounter < 1
        // Convert data again to save it
        // Add data to zip file
        // Generate zip file and save in user's local storage

//uriToBase64() function
```

This way I receive all the data correctly, but the “Generate zip file and save it in user’s local storage” is adding only the first image, and it ends corrupted.

*Attempt 2*

As I said before, I already tried a lot with async/await. I also divided the entire function in smaller functions and tried to async/await on the parts that I need to go first. My last try with async/await look similar to this:

```js
// async Main Function
    // Get some local data
    // Convert to some format I need to edit
    // Loop through user's local images
        // Edit the converted data to add the image's names to it
        // Convert IMAGE to base64 and add result into zip file
        let result = await that.uriToBase64(imageFilePath);
                console.log(result);
                zip.file(arrayItem2.name, result, {base64: true});

    // Convert data again to save it
    // Add data to zip file
    // Generate zip file and save it in user's local storage

//uriToBase64() function
```

*Attempt 3*

Okay, after some tests I was able to get the data synchronously from the `uriToBase64()` function in a few different ways. Regardless of how I received base64 strings, the result was always the same after generating the ZIP file: only one zipped and corrupted image inside the file, the other images and the main file were ignored.

It made me wonder: maybe the problem is how the files are being zipped before the ZIP file is generated. So I went after some answers to this question. I found a function included in the JSZIP library which, as I understand it, allows checking the content that has been added to the ZIP file. With that in mind I looked for some related questions, which led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638914/7123439). In this case, each time a file is added, the same function returns the file completion response.

This is what I tried to do:

```
mainFunction() {
    let string64 = 'veryLongBase64String';

    let b64s = [];
    let arrayOfPromises = [];

    b64s.push(string64);
    b64s.push(string64);
    console.log(b64s);

    b64s.forEach((b64, index) => {
        let fileName = index + ".jpg";
        arrayOfPromises.push(this.addFileToZip(fileName, b64)); 
    });

    Promise.all(arrayOfPromises)
    .then(this.zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
        .then((content) => {
            let filePath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/app_downloads/';
            this.file.writeFile(filePath, "testZip.zip", content).then(() => {
                alert("File saved!");
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                alert("Error while creating file: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        })
    );
}

addFileToZip(name: string, b64: string): Promise<string> {
    this.zip.file(name, b64, {base64: true});
    return this.zip.file(name).async("uint8array");
}
```

Comment: use `await`, it will wait for your async to finish. check here: `https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await`

Comment: Thank you, if you check my post I said that already tried a lot with async/await, but with no success. I will add an update to make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-doubt-regarding-an-asynchronous-function-and-how-i-should-correctly-run-it-synchronously/172371/17?u=leonardofmed) by @rapropos

Basically after getting base64 strings, at the time of generating the ZIP file, the generated file type which by default was `blob` was the reason for the error. Changing the type to `arraybuffer` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of "async"-"await" to handle this scenario.

See the example here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-async-await-pipeline

You can move the following login from your snippet to separate file:

```
// Loop through user's local images
    // Edit the converted data to add the image's names to it
    // Convert IMAGE to base64 and add result into zip file
    that.uriToBase64(imageFilePath).then((result) => {
        console.log("image as base64: ", result);
        zip.file(arrayItem2.name, result, {base64: true});
    });
```

And wait on all promises to be resolved using "Promise.all". Then start writing your zip file to storage.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. My next attempt was going to be with a promise based method.

Comment: Sure. Let me know if u still have question. If this answer/example is helpful then pls upvote it.

Comment: I really liked your stackblitz code, but I can't seem to implement with mine. [I edited one so you can see with more detail my actual code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-async-await-pipeline-iqjzkh?file=index.ts), not only the algorithm. There are parts that I found very difficult to separate.

Comment: [My last try](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-async-await-pipeline-bsemvq?file=index.ts). I manage to separate some parts of the code, it looks more promising than my others attempts, but now I receiving only one corrupted image inside the zip file. The other images and the main file are missing.